# How to get and set textarea value by using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a text editor on my form. When I click something in textarea same value displayed in popup of textarea column.

This is my textarea where I have to set result:

```
<textarea name="content" class="text_editor" id="textarea" ></textarea>
```

View page where I have to get result:

```
<div class="form-group mod_mr20">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Notice Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
       <p></p>//display view here
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my preview button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mr5"  data-toggle="modal" type="button" name="submit" data-target="#pre_view" >PREVIEW</button>
```

After display view result in popup user isn't allowed to edit those values

Comment: What is the HTML code of your pop up? Please explain things clearly. Also, you've tagged jQuery so show us what jQuery code you've tried so far.

Comment: Just use `$('#textarea').val()`, [for example](https://jsfiddle.net/m8fo9t3c/). Also add what you tried in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: As soon as you type something in the textarea, is it supposed to show the pop up immediately? Where exactly is the pop up code, though?

Comment: <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
                                            <p></p>
                                        </div> this is my popup code for textarea

Comment: which text-editor are you use?

Comment: As soon as i type something in the textarea, it is  supposed to show the pop up only when i click on a button preview

Comment: Are you using ckeditor, tinymce or bootstrap text editor?

Answer (score 1):

If you use boostrap try this code:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#Your-modal-popup-id', function () {
    alert('hi');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.hidden_color p').html($("#textarea").val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

I think you are trying to get this,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#preview").on('click',function(){
            $('.col-md-9.col-md-offset-1.hidden_color > p').html($('#textarea').val());
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea name="content" class="text_editor" id="textarea" ></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="preview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Preview</button>
<!--Your Model-->
<div class="form-group mod_mr20">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Notice Description</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 hidden_color">
       <p></p>//display view here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i already have popup when i click on preview button..i just want to display data when user enter something in text area box it display same content when i click preview button..

Comment: In above it is showing the same Text entered in Textarea when you click on Preview

Comment: ok but in view did we define id or not,i want to display view in between <p></p>these tags only

Comment: @user3663 I have updated the answer please try this now

Comment: when i click on preview nothing is happened

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/frx7vap7z/Untitled.png   This is the output when you click on Preview

Comment: but i didn't get this